# how to create the webpage in blackberry using java on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

what is the process to developwe the webpage on blackberry phones using of java applications on eclipse environment

Answer (score 1):

First, learn how to use the [Eclipse IDE](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/totalbeginner.html).

Second, learn [Java EE](http://java.sun.com/javaee/reference/tutorials/).

Third, practice, practice, and more practice.  Remember, it's not the destination that's important, it's the journey.